# Remove Duplicates from sorted list not passing all testcases

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, duplicates, singly-linked-list

This is a question on leetcode. For some reason my code only works for 7/164 test cases. i would like to know why my algorithm is not efficient.
what is a solution to this? what is wrong with my code?
here is link to the problem 
https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/description/

edit: i have taken suggestions and edited code but my algorithm is still not passing, i am getting a time limit exceed error. is the algorithm efficient?

```
class Solution {
public:
ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {
    ListNode* current = head;
    ListNode* nex;

    while(current!=NULL){
        nex=current->next;
        if (nex==NULL)
            break;


        if(current->val==nex->val)
            current->next=nex->next;
        if (current->next==NULL)
            break;
        current==current->next;
         if(current->next==NULL)
            break;



    }
    return current;

}
```

};

Comment: The null check on nex should be after nex = current->next

Answer (score 2):

`nex` is not initialized. You try to compare it with `NULL` before it is initialized.

You remove duplicates of the neighbor pairs only. It is OK for sorted lists.

You get into memory leaks.

The final two `if` are odd.

I think you return from the function not what is expected.

Used `==` where `=` should be used.

Your should not change `current` after `current->next` changed.

```
while (current && (nex = current->next)){
    if (current->val == nex->val) {
        current->next = nex->next;
        delete nex;
    } else {
        current = current->next;
    }
}
return head;
```

Comment: so putting nex=current->next; before i compare it to null will fix it? i just got a time limit exceeded error.

Comment: No. There are other errors. You should return `head`. And be careful with `==` where you assumed to have `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Duplicates from Sorted List (JavaScript) -> try this one

```js
let deleteDuplicates = (head) => {
    let inArray = []
    let check =  head.reduce((a, c) => {
        if(a[c]) a[c] = ++a[c];
        else a[c] = 1;
        return a
    },{})
    for (var i in check) {
        if (check[i] == 1) inArray.push(Number(i))
    }
    return inArray;
}
let output = deleteDuplicates([3,7,4,4,2])
console.log(output)
```